# What is the variable signifying the TFS project name?

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

I am creating a Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2008 build agent for a project of mine. For the working directory, we don't use the default $(Temp)\$(BuildDefinitionPath). Instead of Temp, we use a specific folder. That folder path includes the Team Project's name. Here comes my question. Is there a variable replacement for the Team Project's name.

Example Working directory:
D:\Builds\BuildAgents\AdventureWorld\$(BuildDefinitionPath)

I want to replace AdventureWorld with a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$(MSBuildProjectName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx):

> The file name of the project file without the file name extension, for example, MyApp.

Comment: Well, this is the answer, but not the solution. 

So the variable name does as it says, BUT I see I needed to ask a slightly different question: Can I use variables when defining the Drop Folder during the queueing of a build. 

D:\Builds\BuildAgents\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(BuildDefinitionPath) didn't replace the variable names. It created this literal folder structure. 

Oh well. thanks for the quick & very helpful reply

Comment: In order to avoid creating the literal folder structure edit the project file by hand instead of using the project Properties -> Build tab.

Answer (score 2):

One more resource I found

http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/30_useful_team.html